# proof that every basis for a vector space has the same number of elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I trying to understand the following proof from Bhattacharya's First Course in Linear Algebra (pp. 131-2):

[image]

[image]

I've boxed in red the part I'm having trouble with. To be specific, I'm not clear on why there's a need here to consider two cases: the case of $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\subseteq W$ and the case of $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\not\subseteq W$. As far as I can tell, the proof given for the case $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\not\subseteq W$ works even if $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\subseteq W$. But I imagine the author wouldn't break into cases if it weren't necessary to do so, so I suspect I might be missing something.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Try tracking that proof through step by step. If we can't find $x_n$ not belonging to $W$, then it's possible that $\alpha_m=0$, and then...?

Comment: @GregMartin But isn't the fact that some $\alpha_m$ is non-zero guaranteed by $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$'s being linearly independent? As in, if $S=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is linearly independent, then $0\notin S$, and so if $x_n=\alpha_1u_1+\cdots+\alpha_mu_m$, then at least one $\alpha_i$ is non-zero.

Comment: It isn't just _some_ $\alpha_i$ that is assumed to be non-zero. It is specifically the _last_ $\alpha_m$ that is presumed to be non-zero. The coefficient that pairs with $u_m$, the one vector in the generating set of $V$ that isn't (guaranteed to be) in $W$.

Comment: @Arthur I'm really not seeing how/where the argument breaks down if $\alpha_i$ is taken to be arbitrary.

Comment: They defined $W$ as the set generated by $\{u_1, \dots, u_{m-1}\}$. They could have held off defining $W$ until after they'd picked $x_n$, defined the $a_i$, and picked a $k$ with $a_k \ne 0$. Then indeed they could have defined $W$ to be the span of $\{u_i : i \ne k\}$. Where upon the rest of the argument works with full generality. Why didn't they? Because they found the argument above simpler. Just defining $W$ at the start as they did and noting that the case where all $x_i \in W$ is trivial, handled the difficulty more easily than your alternative.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the response. That's how I did it, i.e. defined $W$ later on. Admittedly it does appear smoother with $W$ defined in advance. But good to know both options are valid.